# How to get last inserted row id from sqlite in phonegap android

Tags: cordova, android-sqlite, lastinsertid

I am creating an app in which i am inserting a data in the table. After inserting the data in the table i want to get the id of that row so i can do further operation depending on it.
I tried to use **last_insert_rowid()** function of sqlite but found no luck.
can any one tell which is the best way to get last inserted row id.
Any idea is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: last_insert_rowid() should have worked. Did your insert go through?

Comment: hope you are using the correct query SELECT last_insert_rowid(). Do not include the table name

Comment: i may use it in wrong way can you give me an example of it and how to pass the result to the variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the id of the last insert on a table like this -

```
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO profile('name','label','list_order','category') values(?,?,?,?)", 
    [currentProfile.name, currentProfile.label, currentProfile.list_order, currentProfile.category], 
    function(tx, results){
        var lastInsertId = results.insertId; // this is the id of the insert just performed
    }, 
    failCB
)
```

The `results.insertId` in WebSQL is similar to `mysql_insert_id()` in MySQL -

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Do you maybe know how i could get the row data i just inserted from this result set as well.

Comment: @Neil In the example above you can reference the `currentProfile` object.  I imagine in your case you might have this inside of a loop.  In that case you could wrap the `tx.executeSql` inside of a closure so that it keeps scope on the `currentProfile` object.

Comment: sadly not. in my case it is not in a for-loop. but the data is retrieved from all the textbox obects. the problem is there are about 20. and was hoping there is an easy way to get a resource object that has all the properties set already from the result set. because I pass the object that is created in the success event and pass that on to the viewing page.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a column in your table named rowid, oid, or _rowid_? If you do, that will cause an issue with `last_insert_rowid()` working as intended. See [here](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html).

A workaround:
If you have an ID column that is auto-incremented, you could use the following SQL to get the last entry.

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable ORDER BY yourIdColumn DESC LIMIT 1
```

It's hacky, but it would work.

Comment: This will not work if you also delete records from your db. The new records take ids of the deleted records